# Increment through a list on a button list

Tags: c#, list

I've stored a list of colors in my program. I am after an object in my scene to one of the colors in the list. So far, I have done the followings:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < claddingColor.Count; i++)
    {
        claddingMaterial.color = claddingColor[i];
    }
}
```

This isn't working due to a reason I know (and you can probably spot) but I lack to the verbal fortitude to write it down.

As opposed to have a multiple lines of the following:

```
claddingMaterial.color = claddingColor[0];
```

Each tied to different buttons, I like a way I can emulate the above but tie it to a single button press. Thus, if I hit the 0 button 5 times, it will loop through each color stored in the list. If I hit it for a sixth time, it will go back to the first color in the list.

Could someone please help me implement this? Or point me to something that I may learn how to do it for myself?

Comment: Updated. Is that clearer? Sorry for poor explanation.

Comment: Still not clear what you really want to do. Why the for loop?

Comment: @N0xus it's better now, check my answer.

Comment: Thank you, totally re-wrote the question once my brain woke up. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need a for loop

```
int lastStep = 0;

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
{
    claddingMaterial.color = claddingColor[lastStep++];
    if (lastStep == claddingColor.Count)
        lastStep = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define LastColor property as class member:

```
int LastColor;
```

In your function use modulo

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
{
    claddingMaterial.color = claddingColor[(LastColor++) % claddingColor.Count];
}
```

Note: Depending on the type of claddingColor use `Count` for a List or `Length` for Array.